# How to get the selected rows from DT within the popup modal (user action)

Tags: r, shiny

I used ShinyBS package to make a popup modal. When I hit view, it pops up a window.  Inside of the popup modal is a data table made by the DT package. I wanted to select rows and display the ID number of the row I selected at the bottom of the popup window. However, I don't know what's the correct "Input" name to get it. 
The following is my sample code.

```
#rm(list = ls())
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)

# This function will create the buttons for the datatable, they will be unique
shinyInput <- function(FUN, len, id, ...) {inputs <- character(len)
for (i in seq_len(len)) {
  inputs[i] <- as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), ...))}
inputs
}

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Simple App"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",
                menuItem("Menu Item 1", tabName = "one", icon = icon("dashboard"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "one",h2("Datatable Modal Popup"),
              DT::dataTableOutput('my_table'),uiOutput("popup")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  my_data <- reactive({
    testdata <- cars
    as.data.frame(
      cbind(
      View = shinyInput(actionButton, 
                        nrow(testdata),
                        'button_', 
                        label = "View", 
                        onclick = 'Shiny.onInputChange(\"select_button\",  this.id)' ),
      testdata))
  })  
  output$my_table <- DT::renderDataTable(my_data(),selection = 'single',options = list(searching = FALSE,pageLength = 10),server = FALSE, escape = FALSE,rownames= FALSE)

  SelectedRow <- eventReactive(input$select_button,{
    as.numeric(strsplit(input$select_button, "_")[[1]][2])
  })
  observeEvent(input$select_button, {
    toggleModal(session, "modalExample", "open")
  })

  DataRow <- eventReactive(input$select_button,{
    iris
  })

  ## I guess my input name is not right
  output$y11 = renderPrint(input$popup_rows_selected)


  output$popup <- renderUI({
    bsModal("modalExample", paste0("Data for Row Number: ",SelectedRow()), "", size = "large",
            column(12,                   
                   DT::renderDataTable(DataRow()),
                   h4("The following didn't show when I select the rows"),
                   verbatimTextOutput('y11')

            )
    )
  })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work, the event has to be bound to the table id, which you had it for ui element(can contain multiple things)

```
#rm(list = ls())
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)

# This function will create the buttons for the datatable, they will be unique
shinyInput <- function(FUN, len, id, ...) {inputs <- character(len)
for (i in seq_len(len)) {
  inputs[i] <- as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), ...))}
inputs
}

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Simple App"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",
                menuItem("Menu Item 1", tabName = "one", icon = icon("dashboard"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "one",h2("Datatable Modal Popup"),
              DT::dataTableOutput('my_table'),uiOutput("popup")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  my_data <- reactive({
    testdata <- cars
    as.data.frame(
      cbind(
        View = shinyInput(actionButton, 
                          nrow(testdata),
                          'button_', 
                          label = "View", 
                          onclick = 'Shiny.onInputChange(\"select_button\",  this.id)' ),
        testdata))
  })  
  output$my_table <- DT::renderDataTable(my_data(),selection = 'single',options = list(searching = FALSE,pageLength = 10),server = FALSE, escape = FALSE,rownames= FALSE)

  SelectedRow <- eventReactive(input$select_button,{
    as.numeric(strsplit(input$select_button, "_")[[1]][2])
  })
  observeEvent(input$select_button, {
    toggleModal(session, "modalExample", "open")
  })

  DataRow <- eventReactive(input$select_button,{
    iris
  })

  ## I guess my input name is not right
  output$y11 = renderPrint(input$my_test_rows_selected)


  output$my_test <- DT::renderDataTable(DataRow())

  output$popup <- renderUI({
    bsModal("modalExample", paste0("Data for Row Number: ",SelectedRow()), "", size = "large",
            column(12,                   
                   dataTableOutput("my_test"),
                   h4("The following didn't show when I select the rows"),
                   verbatimTextOutput('y11')

            )
    )
  })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]